# Cpanel : Joomla site 500 Internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla, joomla1.5

I am continuously getting this error- 500 Internal server error on my Joomla 1.5 website.

Found solution 1-My folder permissions are 755 and files are 644 (even getting the same error with 755). >>>Not working :(

Found Solution 2-.htaccess related error. >>>There is no .htaccess at all, still site was running fine for last two years.

Error log says (file at the rrot of my site)- "PHP Fatal error:  [Zend Guard Loader] Extension "Zend Guard Loader" cannot be loaded twice in Unknown on line 0".

The error log from Cpanel root says- "Permission denied: [client IP:PORT] AH00529: /home/mysite/public_html/administrator/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/mysite/public_html/administrator/' is executable".

Can't proceed with this error for quite a long duration (for 6 to 7 days).

An immediate help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Guard Loader is not used by Joomla so with all probability is one of the latest extensions you installed (plugins / modules). I bet on modules because that would explain the "cannot be loaded twice" module.

If you are really sure you did not install anything, your site may have been hacked and you need to check carefully for malicious files in your site folders.

Answer (score 0):

I would see if your hosting company is able to disable Zend Gaurd in your php conifg.

Also in your Joomla configuration.php disable SEO urls and change .htaccess to htaccess.bak to see if that gives you access again.

Answer (score 0):

check if the .htaccess in Admin-Folder is still present and working!